# Recovering MySQL Databases from Total Failure

Tags: mysql, server-crashes

MySQL was not starting. I backed up /var/lib/mysql/*. I uninstalled MySQL and reintalled it. It started again. I copied everything back to /var/lib/mysql. I restarted the service. I logged in and could see all of my tables. When I try to view their contents, I get:

Table 'tablename' doesn't exist

Is there something I need to do to make MySQL recognize the files I copied back into the /var/lib/mysql/ folder?

Any help is appreciated, I'm dying here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check permissions, make sure ownership and permissions are correct on `/var/lib/mysql`. This is typically `mysql`.  If this is not the issue, produce output of your `.err` log file.

Try the following to correct permissions:

```
chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql
find /var/lib/mysql -type d -exec chmod 770 {} \;
find /var/lib/mysql -type f -exec chmod 660 {} \;
```

The error log is located in the data directory, which appears to be `/var/lib/mysql` in your case.  Verify in your cnf file.

Comment: I ran chmod -R 777 /var/lib/mysql/ and still had the same problem. Where is the mysql error log located in a standard Ubuntu install?

Comment: Bad idea, should almost never have public writable stuff.  Check out my edit.

Comment: Thanks for the tweak on permissions. On closer inspection I found that some of my tables existed, and others didnt. Looks like data corruption killed the tables that weren't being found.I found a backup of everything and reimported the data from the backup (thank goodness!).

Comment: I'm glad everything worked out!